# Como levantar 2 interfaces de red en centos

Tags: linux, redes, centos

Tengo un server que cuenta con 2 interfaces de red. Uno a una IP publica y otro a una ip privada. El de la IP privada tiene que mirar un proxy.

Cuando levanto cualquiera de las 2 IP en una de las interfaces funciona bien. Es decir. Si levanto la IP publica me da acceso a internet, o si levanto la privada, veo el proxy.

Sin embargo, tengo problemas al levantar las 2 al mismo tiempo. ¿Algún consejo al respecto? y, también, por qué, cuando levanto la IP privada, no puedo ver otras maquinas que se supone están en la misma LAN?

Saludos y gracias

Comment: Esto parece mas una pregunta para la comunidad Super User que para Stack Overflow en español, o cual es el criterio de preguntas.

Comment: Estamos a ciegas. Quizas deberias copiarnos la configuracion de las 2 interfaces

Answer (score 0):

Hola revisa los log  para ver problemas  con las  interfaces al levantarlas y  por otro lado cuando levantas la ip publica revisa  que llegues a tu gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Saber cuál es la versión de CentOS es fundamental: La red en 7 se configura toalmente distinto que en 6 y anteriores.

Pegar la configuración de los archivos que tienes en `/etc/sysconfig/network-script/ifcfg-*` puede ayudar también.